# How to fix 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'''?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm setting up a simple Python3.X server, but there is a TypeError that I can't solve.

I've tried this type of server on a Ubuntu Desktop machine, but on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, it does not seem to work.

```
def main():
    socket.bind(('', 8000))
    socket.listen(5)

    while True:
        connection, address = socket.accept()
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode()
        data_bak = data
```

It should be working, but this error shows up:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

I verified, but there is no 'tuple' in my code

Comment: Which line do you get the error?

Comment: The ` socket.bind(('', 8000))` line

Comment: There are actually multiple tuples in your code. But I cannot reproduce the error you mention with your code (not even if I add the imports and the call to `main`). Are you sure you posted the right code and error message? Please first take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to define a `socket` object first, and then call [bind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) on that object, and then call subsequent function on that socket object

A good starting example is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example)

```
In [18]: from socket import socket                                                                                                                        
In [19]: s = socket()                                                                                                                                     
In [20]: s.bind(('',8000))  
In [21]: s.listen(5)                                                                                                                                      
In [22]:
```